# How do I help my console application find all the referenced assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net-core, assembly-binding-redirect, assembly-references, assemblyversions

**tl;dr:** My .NET Core 3.1 console application crashes with a `FileNotFoundException` because a (referenced?) assembly is present in version A, but required in version B. What to do?

---

I am trying to get a console application to run that is now built for .NET Core 3.1, but that used to be a .NET Framework 4.8 project before it was converted.

The console application crashes with a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`, saying that the assembly *Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical* in version *3.1.0.0* cannot befound. Now, I can confirm it's not there - in the directory where the `.exe` file of my console application resides, there is a file named *Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll*, but its assembly version is *3.1.6.0*.

The console application and its dependencies are a part of a bigger project in said folder, with a total of over 1,200 DLLs.

In .NET Framework, I'd have used a binding redirect to use the present version 3.1.6.0 of the indicated assembly. In .NET Core, though, I understand these binding redirects are not a thing anymore. Thus, I'm not sure how to proceed, or how to even find out why the runtime thinks it needs to load *Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll*.

I may have found a partial solution that loads the version-mismatched assembly nonetheless (see observation (6) below), but then, I'm still getting a `FileNotFoundException`, this time for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions`.

Some observations and attempts to solve this:

- (1) None of the > 1,200 `.csproj` files contains the string "Physical".
- (2) More than 400 of the `.deps.json` files mention "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll", all of them referring to version 3.1.0.0.
- (3) All of the respective DLLs are loaded in an ASP.NET Core application where the version mismatch appears to cause no issues.
- (4) The `.deps.json` file of my console application itself does not mention "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll".
- (5) Putting the right version of the file (3.1.0.0) into the directory where the `.exe` file resides and from where the `.exe` file is also executed does not change anything. The `FileNotFoundException` still occurs, still complaining about an absence of "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll", version 3.1.0.0.
- (6) Based upon the information on assembly resolution in .NET Core provided in [a CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194332/Resolving-Assemblies-in-NET-Core), I have attempted to force loading of the assemblies from the same directory myself (preliminary code, relying on the working directory):

  ```
  AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving += (context, name) =>
  {
    var dllPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, name.Name + ".dll");

    if (File.Exists(dllPath))
    {
      return AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(dllPath);
    }

    return null;
  };
  ```

  **This appears to help to some extent!** Now, the "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll" assembly, and plenty (more than 250) of others, can be loaded. But this fails once "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions", 3.1.0.0, needs to be loaded, which is not actually anywhere around the `.exe` file. Apparently, it must be loaded from somewhere else (?)
- (7) While the above appears to provide a partial solution concerning the version mismatch, our entire source code contains no other occurrence of "AssemblyLoadContext". Therefore, the ASP.NET Core application apparently avoids the version mismatch issue using some other mechanism.
- (8) Building my console application with build output set to *Diagnostic*<sup>1</sup> confirms the suspected behaviour for the "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll" file (shortened excerpt of the output):

  ```
  Dependency "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
        For SearchPath "C:\(...)".
        Considered "C:\(...)\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.winmd", but it didn't exist.
        Considered "C:\(...)\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll",
            but its name "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, Version=3.1.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"
            didn't match the expected name "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
        Considered "C:\(...)\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.exe", but it didn't exist.
    Required by "(A)".
    Required by "(B)".
    Required by "(C)".
  ```

  In there, (A), (B), and (C) are assemblies of our own project. But as far as I can see, neither of their `.csproj` files mentions the text "Physical", so I do not understand why the DLL is allegedly being required by them.
- (9) For the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" assembly, diagnostic output says:

  ```
  Dependency "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
        For SearchPath "C:\(...)".
        Considered "C:\(...)\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.winmd", but it didn't exist.
        Considered "C:\(...)\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll", but it didn't exist.
        Considered "C:\(...)\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.exe", but it didn't exist.
        Considered "C:\(...)\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.winmd", but it didn't exist.
        Considered "C:\(...)\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll", but it didn't exist.
        Considered "C:\(...)\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.exe", but it didn't exist.
    Required by "(B)".
  ```

  Once again, (B) is an assembly (same as the (B) in (8)) of our own, but looking into the `.csproj` file does not reveal a single occurrence of "Mvc.Abstractions".

---

I have found a couple of questions that appeared to provide solutions, but none of them worked for me:

- [*Assembly binding redirect in .NET Core*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64128002/assembly-binding-redirect-in-net-core) - just points to another question (listed below).
- [*Adding a bindingRedirect to a .Net Standard library*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111749/adding-a-bindingredirect-to-a-net-standard-library) - the answer points out that binding redirects do not exist in .NET Core, but that the `.deps.json` file can be used to resolve assemblies. It then goes on to describe .NET Framework binding redirects, without mentioning anything else on what to do with `.deps.json` in .NET Core.
- [*Common practice to load the dependency(different version of dll) in program*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034938/common-practice-to-load-the-dependencydifferent-version-of-dll-in-program) - the question is about .NET Core, but the answer applies to .NET Framework. For .NET Core, it links to one of the other questions listed here.
- [*How can I add an assembly binding redirect to a .net core unit test project?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252136/how-can-i-add-an-assembly-binding-redirect-to-a-net-core-unit-test-project) - the answers to this question seem to suggest using binding redirects in `app.config` files, even though these are apparently not supported anymore in .NET Core according to another comment on that question. In any case, the suggested solution of adding

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
      <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
      <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```

  to the `.csproj` file (uh, which one? I tried the one of my console application; is that the right one?) has no effect to my `.deps.json` files or the exception I keep getting, as far as I can tell.
- [*Error System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.8.0 in .NET Core*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55156948/error-system-io-fileloadexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-log4net-ve) - in this case, the correct DLL was available in the right version, it was just not copied to the appropriate output folder.
- [*.NET Core 3.1 - Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59610009/net-core-3-1-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4-2-2-0) - the solution in this case seemed to be to use another library/library version that would fit with the assembly reference. I do not think that is a viable way for me, as replacing the *Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical* assembly might just cause any kinds of conflicts or issues in any of the > 400 of our assemblies that apparently somehow use the file, according to the `.deps.json` mentions.
- [*Why is my .NET framework app looking for the wrong version of the .NET core/standard platform extension assembly, and how do I fix it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742297/why-is-my-net-framework-app-looking-for-the-wrong-version-of-the-net-core-stan) - it seems this question's OP just accidentally stepped into the .NET Core topic, while they were actually working in a .NET Framework context.
- [*FileNotFoundException when referencing DLL in .NET Core Application*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176640/filenotfoundexception-when-referencing-dll-in-net-core-application) - this issue was centered around deficiencies in earlier .NET Core versions, which do not apply to .NET Core 3.1 anymore.
- [*FileNotFoundException with indirectly (.net to .net standard to NuGet) referenced DLL*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712528/filenotfoundexception-with-indirectly-net-to-net-standard-to-nuget-reference) - this appears to have been another case of the correct DLL file being available, just not in the right location.
- [*Can I control .NET Core assembly redirects programmatically?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040563/can-i-control-net-core-assembly-redirects-programmatically) - once again, comments in this question point out that binding redirects are not a solution in .NET Core. Moreover, the answer appears to apply to compile time. As none of our `.csproj` files mentions the files with which I am observing a version mismatch, I suspect it is referenced from within one of the 3rd party libraries we are using and thus compile-time solutions may not be applicable.

---

**How can I make the runtime load version of 3.1.6.0 of the indicated assembly rather than the requested version 3.1.0.0? Alternatively, how do I find out how the runtime does it when running the ASP.NET Core application?**

---

<sup>1</sup>: in VS2019: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build And Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity -> Diagnostic

Comment: Have you tried explicitly installing required version of [`Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical` nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical/)?

Comment: @GuruStron: As mentioned in the question, I don't think I should attempt to replace the DLL file. More than 400 of our assemblies mention it in their `.deps.json` files and I do not want to risk breaking anything in those. If I cannot find any other ways, though, I will try that locally tomorrow just to check whether I at least arrive at another outcome in the console application.

Comment: Which version of Core 3.1 are you using?  See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1

Comment: @jdweng: There appears to be [no good way to obtain the currently running .NET Core version](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Apr/12/Getting-the-NET-Core-Runtime-Version-in-a-Running-Application), but the latest 3.1.* version of .NET Core on my machine is 3.1.14.

Comment: You have to make sure all the pieces of your project is built with same version.  Even then there may be bugs in the library.  The left column of my link is the versions you should use when building app.  The right column is the runtime library that you use when you deploy on a machine after building.

Comment: @jdweng: On my machine, I have .NET Core SDK 3.1.408 installed. But you're saying it can be problematic if some parts of our team are using that version, while other parts of the team are using version 3.1.114? We may be able to mandate a certain SDK version for our own developers, but how do we ensure the very same SDK version has been used for building 3rd party binaries?

Comment: @GuruStron: Curiously, putting exactly the referenced DLL file ( `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60` ) into the same directory where the console application `.exe` file resides, and from where it is launched, does not change anything. That is, the `FileNotFoundException` still occurs, still complaining about an inability to find version 3.1.0.0 of that file.

Comment: Can you create a reproducer? Do you have a global.json file and if yes what are the contents? Try performing full clean up (delete bin and objs folders, for example you can use `git clean -fdx`, beware it will delete all not committed changes also)

Comment: Also build the project with verbose setting on, sometimes it can give hints what's going wrong.

Comment: @GuruStron: "Can you create a reproducer?" - unfortunately, I don't know how. The framework that is loaded along with the console application will dynamically attempt to load all of the > 1,200 assemblies (for dependency injection). If I *knew* the dependency chain that leads up to the files in question (= the subset of files relevant to the problem), I would probably be quite a bit closer to a solution in the first place.

Comment: @GuruStron: By global JSON file, are you referring to a `.deps.json` file with the same name as my console application `.exe`? Such a file is generated, ye. It has roughly 350 lines, should I look for anything specific?

Comment: @GuruStron: I have updated the question with additional observations from diagnostic output (as well as an attempted solution using DIY assembly reolution that appears to bring a step forward, though does not entirely remove the problem).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper check the build output before the error - sometimes the actual issue is described there. Also I believe the dependency chain can be found in that output (also it is not an easy thing to do). Have you tried to delete bin and objs folders? Have you tried to build the erroneous project standalone?

Comment: You need to have 3rd party provide a installation package with setup.exe.  For a Net application to run on a remote machine either you need the same version of Net on Build and Deploy machine, or you need to install like commercial software.  A lot of the Net library are wrappers with just call a Windows Dll.  What setup.exe does is updates the Windows dlls so deploy machine so deploy version of dll is same as build version.

Comment: @GuruStron: In the build output, the assemblies are mentioned in a long, long list of referenced assemblies. I haven't spotted anything noteworthy before that in the log so far. And, to be clear: Despite MSBuild mentions of missing assemblies, **I am not getting any build errors.** The errors I describe in this question entirely occur **at runtime**. Deleting `bin` and `obj` doesn't change anything; after rebuilding the console application and running it, it still behaves absolutely the same, failing to find the mentioned assemblies. What exactly do you mean by "standalone" - outside of VS?

Comment: @jdweng: I'll look more into that, but I do wonder: If *that* were the problem, how could the full ASP.NET Core application that uses the very same assembly files work (which it does!)?

Comment: Look at the link I provided with the different versions of Core 3.1.  Read the notes above the the first two releases in the right column.  The second release says "This release includes the .NET Runtime, you do not need to install it separately."  The latest release says "On Windows, we recommend installing the Hosting Bundle, which includes the .NET Runtime and IIS support."

Comment: @jdweng: Well, I *have* the hosting bundle of 3.1.14 on my machine.

Comment: I think the Microsoft Build has bugs. Core is suppose to be a compact version of Net to run on mobile devices that has less memory.  So the previous release started getting too large.  So they separated out some libraries into the hosting bundle that may not be needed. It looks like some libraries were missed and not included in either the regular build the hosting build.  Then you may be using a feature that should not be used at all in Core.

Comment: @jdweng: So, if I get you correctly, you're saying that the hosting build (which is used for the ASP.NET Core web application) contains the *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions* assembly, while the regular runtime does not? In that case, the question is what makes our assemblies require *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions*. As outlined in observation (9), the assembly indicated by MSBuild does not actually appear to reference *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions*.

Comment: I can't answer that question.  Ask Microsoft.  Microsoft tried to come up with a kludge to solver a problem, but it create other issues like yours.