# Namespace confusion with same structure

Tags: c#, reference, namespaces

I have a issue when i try to add the namespace Azure.Storage.Blobs as using to a class.
It is caused by another referenced NuGet package called CopmanyName.Azure

When i add using Azure.Storage.Blobs it shows me the subnamespaces from CopmanyName.Azure.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0QKP.png)

However i want to add the using from Azure.Storage.Blobs.
This is caused due to a maching project stucture CompanyName.Azure.D365FO and reference NuGet package Company.Azure.

See the sturcture of the main project: [ProjectStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUwB4.png)
and the structure of the referenced project: [ReferencedProjectStructur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJnuP.png)

Is there any way to get arround this problem without changing structures of namespaces in the current projects? So i get to the result below.

```
namespace CompanyName.Azure.Model.CSP
{
#if NET46
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
#else
    using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
#endif
```

Comment: This is becoming a comman issue with Core 3.1.  It is the third time I've seen it this week.  I think something is wrong with latest version of Core 3.1 (see : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1).  Your issue is similar to following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67186636/how-do-i-help-my-console-application-find-all-the-referenced-assemblies#comment118788883_67186636

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself.
Hope some else can use it once.

Add global::

using global::Azure.Storage.Blobs;